# Real-valued harmonic function as NOT the difference of two nonnegative harmonic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

The following is a question that I found on an old qualifying exam:

Find a real-valued harmonic function on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$ that cannot be written as the difference of two nonnegative harmonic functions.

Comment: As a suggestion, you know that nonnegative harmonic functions obey Harnack's inequality, so that might be able to tell you something about the difference of such functions.

Answer (score 1):

1. For any harmonic function, the average   over the circle $|z|=r$ stays the same for all $r<1$, namely it is the value at $0$.
2. If $u=v-w$, then $|u|\le |v|+|w|$.
3. Combine 1 and 2 to conclude: if $u=v-w$ where $v$ and $w$ are nonnegative harmonic functions, then the average   of $|u|$ on the circle $|z|=r$ is bounded by a constant independent of $r$.
4. It remains to find a harmonic function $u$ for which the circular averages of $|u|$ are unbounded. One example is $\operatorname{Re}((1-z)^{-2})$. Indeed, when $|\arg (1-z)|<\pi/8$ it admits the estimate 
   $$\operatorname{Re}(1-z)^{-2} > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} |1-z|^{-2}$$ 
   Since the intersection of the circle $|z|=r$ with the sector  $|\arg (1-z)|<\pi/8$ contains an arc of length of order $r$ on which $|1-z|$ is of order $r$, the claim  follows.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution -

Every non-zero harmonic function $u$ can be written as
$ u = \dfrac{|u|+u}{2} - \dfrac{|u|-u}{2}$. At points where $u>0$, by the identity : $u = u - 0$ and when $u<0$ then $u = 0 - (-u)$. In both the cases, the functions are non-negative. An alternative argument is $|u|\geq u$ and $|u|\geq -u$ for all real valued $u$ and hence the difference functions are always non-negative.

So every real valued harmonic function, $u$ can be written as the difference of two non-negative harmonic functions when $|u|$ is also harmonic. This certainly allows $u$  to be from the set of linear polynomials in $x$ and $y$ that is $u = ax+by$ where $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ as $|u|$ is not harmonic and hence the above identity does not apply.

Comment: The header may not have indicated what I wanted to ask - I've clarified it.  Your solution doesn't work because $|u|$ isn't necessarily harmonic. For example, $x$ is harmonic but $|x|$ isn't since its not $C^1$.

Comment: In fact, $|u|$ is never harmonic when $u$ changes sign: consider the minimum principle.